# Wavelength of light in a gravitational field

Tags: visible-light, wavelength

I'm having a light source which can emit a particular wavelength of light, on an extremely massive planet.
Light will be affected by gravity, **So will the wavelength of the light source increase?**

As per this equation?
$$
p=\frac{h}{\lambda}
$$
If it does so, then is this the reason why extremely massive stars emit **red light**?

Comment: Extremely **massive** stars (like O and B stars) are hot and blue not red. Extremely **large** stars tend to be red because they are usually red giants and quite cool.

Comment: @JohnRennie But,Will the wavelength increase?

Comment: @SathyaramGanapathy: It is almost always a mistake to put two or more questions into a single question here. Its a law: people will only answer what you consider a minor subsidiary question and ignore the question you really wanted answering.

Answer (score 1):

The star emits red light because it has a surface temperature somewhere around 3,500 Kelvin. Our sun has a temperature of about 6,ooo Kelvin so it emits yellow/white light. Like any black body radiation, the temperature determines the frequency of the emitted photons.
As for the gravity potion of your question, I may be wrong but I think you talking about photons that have been linearly slowed down (not their oscillating frequency) so that there wavelength has shifted as with the Doppler effect.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the terminology. The emission of light depends from the temperature of the [emitting body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). The bandwidth goes from infrared to red and blue to ultraviolet than higher the temperature.

Red and blue shift means, that the well known [spectrum from elements like hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series) is shifted to the blue or red side. And yes, this happens due to the doppler effect AND due to gravitational potential. Than more mass has a star than more the spectra are moved to red.